# Is it possible to calculate aligning torque from the driver steering torque?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I'm stuck on deriving the aligning torque because I neither have the lateral force nor the pneumatic trail. Is it possible to derive it from the drivers steering torque considering a rack has translational motion? Any guidance will be appreciated.

[image: Gough Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Well, not really because you would need to know the mechanical trail of the suspension. In the design of suspension hardpoints you could do a centrepoint design with no mech trail, in which case the rack force is proportional to the aligning torque, but that would give maximum effort at about half the maximum latacc, and none at the peak latacc, which would not be very convenient.

Or you might stick loads of mech trail in, and then get SWT more or less proportional to Fy. In practice neither extreme is much used.

But the way the question is written it seems to assume zero mech trail, so yes, you can. You need to use the efficiency, steering ratio and steering wheel torque. Bear in mind the Gough chart is per wheel. It also doesn't give a cg location so you can't work out the weight transfer. It looks like you assume none.

So Fz is 4kN, find the intersection of the wheel torque you've just worked out, read off the sideslip angle, and apply that to a bicycle model for the radius, and work out the SWA from the ackerman angle and the slip.

I must admit that question seems remarkably odd, the assumptions to answer it are crucially important in real life.